# Thyme leaf and Bootstrap changing button color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot w/Thymeleaf & Bootstrap project.  I have a form that does some lengthy processing on the server.  As this is can be a long process, I would like to:

1) Change the button color/text as a visual indicator that something is happening
2) Disable the button so another file cannot be uploaded until the process completes.

Here is my code so far:

```
<form action="search" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${search}"
                  method="post">
.....
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Search"/>
 </form>
```

And my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String search(@ModelAttribute Search search, Model model, Authentication authentication) {

   List<> found = sdnService.findMatches( search );
   model.addAttribute( "results", found );
   return "search";
}
```

I have seen some examples on changing the button color with javascript, but that only handles setting it the first time, now resetting it when the results come back.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You want to conditionally change the CSS styling of the button, so using thymeleaf, you would use th:class or th:classappend with a conditional evaluation as the value. Check the thymeleaf tutorial for examples of both (http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html). Section 7.1 has an example using a th:class and conditional, while th:classappend is used in section 5.4

Comment: Additionally, I think you need to implement some sort of asynchronous callback flow for this task allowing 'sdnService.findMatches( search );' to execute while the '/search' view is periodically refreshed (and renders your disabled+styled Search button) until the model has been passed the correct data. At the moment, your controller is doing everything in a single synchronous request.